# How to target an element inside the anchor tag visited state in css?

Tags: html, css

Here is my plunk

http://plnkr.co/edit/BVhFiVYXWQ3AuflEWjCP?p=preview

I want to apply border to the image inside the anchor tag once the link is visited.

```
 <a href="">
  <img src="some imageurl" style="height:100px; width:100px;"/>
  <p>Description </p>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="" style="border:1px solid red;">
<img src="some imageurl" style="height:100px; width:100px;"/>
<p>Description </p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
a:visited img {
border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">
     <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" style="height:100px; width:100px;"/>
    <p>Description </p>
   </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a:visited img {
    border:3px solid red;
}
```

Comment: you can improve the answer by proper code formatting and some explanation